# Unable to insert value in MySQL table - Using Phpseclib & MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, phpseclib

I am able to connect to a remote server and its MySQL database through phpseclib library and  trying to insert data into one of its table.

When i try to insert by passing a string, its successful. But when i try to insert by passing a variable. Nothing gets inserted. It shows as -> ( INSERT INTO test_execution (test_desc) values ("") ).

Below is an example of the problem i am facing. Can anyone point out where the problem lies?

```
$desc= $_GET['desc'];
echo "$desc"; // outputs as "testcolumn"

// SUCCESS when passed as a string

 echo $ssh->exec('mysql -h localhost -u root -pXXXX dbname -e "INSERT INTO test_execution (test_desc) values ( \"testcolumn\" );"');

// ERROR when passed as a parameter

 echo $ssh->exec('mysql -h localhost -u root -pXXXX dbname -e "INSERT INTO test_execution (test_desc) values (\'$desc\');"');
```

Comment: Try this:
`echo $ssh->exec('mysql -h localhost -u root -pXXXX dbname -e "INSERT INTO test_execution (test_desc) values (\'' . $desc . '\' );"');`

Comment: @DonJajo I am able to login to remote server and its MySQL DB. But when i am running your command. It says : Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: This interprets the MySQL logins are incorrect. Check your login data

Comment: @DonJajo If they are incorrect, why does this command inserts data properly without any error?: echo $ssh->exec('mysql -h localhost -u root -pXXXX dbname -e "INSERT INTO test_execution (test_desc) values ( \"testcolumn\" );"');

Comment: Looking at both codes login data, they look same...I don't see why the other gave login error

Comment: Does it have anything to do with the fact that you're escaping the single quotes in the double-quoted string?